# Reduce `[URLQueryItem]` into `[String: Any]`

Tags: swift, reduce

Currently I've got this chunky `reduce` function...

```
blah: [String: Any] = queryItems.reduce([String: Any]()) {
    (params: [String: Any], queryItem: URLQueryItem) in

    var output = params

    output[queryItem.name] = queryItem.value

    return output
}
```

I'm sure there is a much simpler way of doing this but I can't get my head around how that would work.

Is there a "better" way to do this?

By "better" I mean cleaner, shorter, more elegant, etc...

Comment: Small warning: there can be multiple parameters with the same key and the order of parameters matters for some APIs. Be aware of that when representing query parameters as a dictionary.

Comment: @Sulthan thanks for the warning. For our particular use case that isn’t an issue but I will watch out for the future. Also... I’ll be updating my code in general soon so might not need this in the end. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to use [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127177-reduce) instead of `reduce(_:_)`. This both save you the lines and the overhead of copying `params` for each iteration:

```
let blah: [String: Any] = (urlComponents.queryItems ?? []).reduce(into: [:]) {
    params, queryItem in 
    params[queryItem.name] = queryItem.value
}
```

> This method is preferred over `reduce(_:_:)` for efficiency when the result is a copy-on-write type, for example an Array or a Dictionary.

Comment: `reduce(into:)` is one of those great unknown gems of recent Swift. Finally makes non-scalar `reduce` usable.

Comment: And Swift is a type inferred Language. Btw you could simply use optional chaining here `let blah = urlComponents.queryItems?.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.name] = $1.value }  ?? [:]` No need to use Any as the value type  if the value will always be a String

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary from the name and value of each query item with

```
let items = urlComponents.queryItems ?? []
let dict = Dictionary(items.lazy.map { ($0.name, $0.value as Any) },
                      uniquingKeysWith: { $1 })
```

In the case of a duplicate name, the later value wins (this can be controlled with the `uniquingKeysWith:` parameters).

Or remove the `as Any` cast to get a dictionary of type `[String: String?]`:

```
let items = urlComponents.queryItems ?? []
let dict = Dictionary(items.lazy.map { ($0.name, $0.value ) },
                      uniquingKeysWith: { $1 })
```

Alternatively

```
let items = urlComponents.queryItems ?? []
let dict = Dictionary(items.lazy.map { ($0.name, [$0.value] ) },
                      uniquingKeysWith: +)
```

to build a dictionary of type `[String : [String?]]`, holding *all* values for each name.